# Get the most important words in the corpus using tf-idf (Gensim)

Tags: python, gensim, tf-idf

I am calculating tf-idf as follows.

```
texts=['human interface computer',
 'survey user computer system response time',
 'eps user interface system',
 'system human system eps',
 'user response time']

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus)
corpus_tfidf = tfidf[corpus]
analyzedDocument = namedtuple('AnalyzedDocument', 'word tfidf_score')
d=[]
for doc in corpus_tfidf:
    for id, value in doc:
        word = dictionary.get(id)
        score = value
        d.append(analyzedDocument(word, score))
```

However, now I want to identify the most 3 important words in my corpus using the words that has the highest `idf` values. Please let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting your list d ok, you should be able to get it arranged as follows: At top:

```
from operator import itemgetter
```

Then at bottom:

```
e=sorted(d, key=itemgetter(1))
top3 = e[:3]
print(top3)
```